# how can I convert a date var to a number is sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this statements

```
SELECT @startdate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -7) -- Monday of previous week
SELECT @enddate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -1) -- Sunday of previous week
```

and I want to convert @startdate and @enddate to numbers in the following format 'yyyymmdd'

Comment: mine is corrected and tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(8), @StartDate, 112)
```

Will convert `2014-03-31` to `20140331`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `year()`, `month()`, and `day()`:

```
select @startdate = year(getdate())*10000 + month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,@startdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
   RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(mm,@startdate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) +
   RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(dd,@startdate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

But this is better:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(8), @StartDate, 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CONVERT

```
declare @enddate smalldatetime
SELECT @enddate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -1) 
select convert(varchar(30), @enddate, 112)
```